# Does Idris have non-terminating terms?

Tags: idris

On the Unofficial FAQ on the official Idris wiki (official in that it is on the language's git repo), it is [stated that](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/wiki/Unofficial-FAQ#why-isnt-idris-lazy)

> in a total language [e.g. Idris] we don't have undefined and non-terminating terms
>   so we need not worry about evaluating them.

However, the following definition for `ones` (using `List` instead of `Stream`) certainly seems non-terminating:

```
ones: List Int
ones = 1 :: ones
-- ...
printLn(head ones) -- seg fault!
```

So, I'm not sure if the wiki entry is mistaken, or if I misunderstand the context. Note the `Stream` workaround is already [described in the Idris tutorial](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#codata-types).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Idris is only total if you ask it to be total. You may write one of `%default total`, `%default covering`, or `%default partial` (the default), and all declarations afterwards will take on the given totality annotation:

```
%default total

-- implicitly total
ones1 : List Int
ones1 = 1 :: ones1
-- ERROR: ones1 is not total

-- total
ZNeverHeardOfIt : Nat -> Nat
ZNeverHeardOfIt (S n) = n
-- ERROR: missing cases in ZNeverHeardOfIt

covering
natRoulette : Nat -> Nat
natRoulette Z = Z
natRoulette (S n) = natRoulette (S (S n))
-- covering means all possible inputs are covered by an equation
-- but the function isn't checked for termination
-- natRoulette has cases for all inputs, but it might go into an infinite loop
-- it's morally equivalent to just partial, as a function that loops forever
-- on an input isn’t very different from one missing the case
-- it just gets the compiler to complain more

partial
ones : List Int
ones = 1 :: ones
-- no checks at all
-- Idris, being strict, needs to evaluate ones strictly before it can evaluate ones.
-- Oh wait, that's impossible. Idris promptly vanishes in a segfault.
```